# Simulink - Algebraic Loops errors

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink

I'm trying to build a system in Simulink, but I get errors about Algebraic Loops.
Could you please help?

The goal of this system is to observe behaviour of double pendulum with a spring attached to the lower part of it.

Here's my system: http://1drv.ms/1GPqeeQ

I can't post pictures, because i don't have enough points on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yep it's common problem.
The problem is that simulink try to use variable value to calculate itself (at one step).
You can solve this problem easily - you just need to add Unit Delay block for this variable. Like this:
[image]

You can see I use variable Vd to calculate itself again at every step.
I added Unit Delay and simulink use the value of Vd from PREVIOUS STEP!
It works perfectly!

Comment: OK, so I added 2 delays and now there are no errors during building of my model. But when I try to run I get an error: Derivative of state '1' in block 'Podwojne_wahadlo_sprezyna/Integrator2' at time 0.0 is not finite. The simulation will be stopped. There may be a singularity in the solution.  If not, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances).   Here's my model: http://1drv.ms/1fq5qAn   I tried adding more delays, but I can't manage to get it running. Can you help me? Oh, and I set solver to ode14x (fixed-step)

Comment: I can't open your model (i can't see some simulink files, only some xml)...
But I can tell you what is the problem - you have infinity value at the entrance of Integrator2. I think, you try to divide some value at 0 and get Infinity value at time 0.0. You need no more delays!
You need to use some specific conditions for time = 0.0 to avoid dividing at zero. For example:
`if t == 0.0 y = 0.0001 else y = 1/t; end`

Comment: I have the same problem. I am trying to solve it but nothing until now :(

Comment: @minidiable can you clarify please - you have the same loop problem or integrator problem?

Comment: Sorry. I had the same problem with the integrator. I put a delay block and it worked (actually I put a so-called MEMORY block).